# Overwriting referenced value of pointer to abstract class has no effect

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class

I am trying to overwrite the object that a pointer to an abstract class points to with an object derived from that class.
However the value does not change.
If I do the same with a pointer to a non-abstract class, everything works as intended.

My guess would be that the compiler refuses to overwrite the memory because it does not know the exact size of of the object that is written at compile-time.

Is there a way that lets me overwrite the object?

Below is a piece of code to demonstrate what I mean.
It is tested using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) and clang (3.2-7ubuntu1).

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Abs {
public:
    virtual const char *toString() = 0;
};

class A: public Abs {
public:
    A(const char *s): st(s) {};
    const char *toString() {return st;};
private:
    const char *st;
};

class B: public Abs {
public:
    B(const char *s): st(s) {};
    const char *toString() {return st;};
private:
    const char *st;
};

int main(void) {
    //works:
    A *a = new A("A");
    printf("a: %s\n", a->toString());
    //output: A

    *a = *(new A("B"));
    printf("a: %s\n", a->toString());
    //output: B

    //doesn't work:
    Abs *x;

    x = new A("A");
    printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
    //output: A

    *x = *(new A("B"));
    printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
    //output: A

    *x = *(new B("C"));
    printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
    //output: A

    Abs *y = new A("D");
    *x = *y;
    printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
    //output: A

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never write `*(new A(....))`.  Ever.  That's a memory leak for no purpose.  Closest correct code would be `*a = A("B");`

Comment: I know this is just for exercise and curiosity, but your code is leaking memory like crazy.

Comment: @FredOverflow only in the places where I say `*a = *(new A("A"));` as pointed out by @Mooing Duck and by not deleting `x` and `a` or also somewhere else? I am still used to Java and sometimes I forget to clean up after myself.

Comment: You have 6 `new`s and 0 `delete`s. How is it not obvious that you are leaking memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider step by step what occurs.

At first you defined pointer to A and initialized it by the address of an object of type A allocated in the heap

```
A *a = new A("A");
printf("a: %s\n", a->toString());
//output: A
```

Then you assigned a new allocated object to the object pointed by a

```
*a = *(new A("B"));
printf("a: %s\n", a->toString());
```

In this case the implicitly defined by the compiler **copy assignment operator for class A** is called and data member st is simply copied from one object to another.

So printf outputs string literal "B".

Now you defined pointer to Abs

```
Abs *x;
```

and initialized it

```
x = new A("A");
printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
//output: A
```

Take into account that the **static type of x is Abs**.

Then in all these statements

```
*x = *(new A("B"));
printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
//output: A

*x = *(new B("C"));
printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
//output: A

Abs *y = new A("D");
*x = *y;
printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
//output: A
```

the **copy assignment operator implicitly defined by compiler for class Abs** is called. Class Abs has no data member st. So it is not changed because in all these cases the copy assignment operator for class Abs is called because **the static type of x is Abs**.

I would like to append that even in this statement that is valid

```
*x = *(new B("C"));
```

the copy assignment operator of class Abs is called. In this case the object of type B allocated in the heap implicitly converted to type Abs.

If you want for example that after statement

```
*x = *(new A("B"));
```

printf would output "B" then you should write

```
*static_cast<A *>( x ) = *(new A("B"));
```

In this case the copy assignment operator for class A will be called.

Also you could write a virtual copy assignment operator in the abstract class. For example

```
class Abs {
public:
    virtual const char *toString() = 0;
    virtual Abs & operator =( const Abd & ) { return *this; }
};
```

and override it for example in class A

```
class A: public Abs {
public:
    A(const char *s): st(s) {};
    const char *toString() {return st;};
    A & operator =( const Abs &rhs ) { st = static_cast<const A &>( rhs ).st; return *this; }
private:
    const char *st;
};
```

In this case after statement

```
*x = *(new A("B"));
```

the next statement will output "B"

```
printf("x: %s\n", x->toString());
//output: B
```

Note: we are not considering memory leaks in your example. We are considering the effect of applying assignment operators.

Comment: that clarifies what's going on. Does it mean that it's not possible to overwrite the abstract object like I want? I know @Kerrek SB gave a workaround but it involves dynamic casting and only overwrites `x` if its dynamic type is appropriate.

Comment: @Till S  If you mean the case *x = *(new A("B")); then you should static_case pointer x to pointer of type A.

Comment: I conclude from the answer that it is not possible to overwrite an object instantiated from an abstract class with an object that is arbitrarily derived from that class.

Comment: @ Till S No, it means that if the left operand of the assignment operator has type of the base class (in your case it is an abstract class) then an object of any derived class in right side of the operator is implicitly converted to an object of the base class and overrides the original object In your example the base class has no data members so you do not see that the original object is overrided with subobject of a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest compilable equivalent to your working code might be this:

```
*static_cast<A*>(x) = *new A("A");
```

Note that the following is undefined behaviour:

```
*static_cast<B*>(x) = *new B("A");
```

That is because the most-derived object is of type `A` and not `B`. Here's a safer approach:

```
if (A * p = dynamic_cast<A*>(x)) { *p = *new A("A"); }
```

Comment: what exactly does most derived mean?
if I have the following code:
`if (...) {x = new A("A");} else {x = new B("B");}`
what would be the most-derived object?

Comment: @TillS: That's a completely different situation -  in the first branch the most derived object of `*x` is `A` and in the second it's `B`.

Comment: ok, my understanding is that I initialize `x` with `x = new A("A");` and that `*x` has size `sizeof (new A("A"))` after that.
If I would overwrite `*x` with something smaller it would be fine but if it's bigger there might be something directly after it in the memory that would be overwritten. And thus the behaviour is undefined.
Wouldn't that mean that `*x` always has the size of the the object that it was last assigned?

Comment: Do you mean "size of" or `sizeof`?

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't involve dynamic casting and always assigns `*x` a new value not only if it has an appropriate dynamic type?

Comment: Why exactly do you insist on overwriting the object? How about simply `a = new B` instead?

Comment: in the scenario that I am interested in there are other pointers besides `a` that point to the same address and I want to change their referenced value without having to change every pointer. e.g. `Abs *a = new A(); Abs *b = a; *a = *(new B());`

Comment: @TillS: `*x` will always be an object of type `Abs`. It just isn't necessarily most-derived, since it may be a subobject of another, larger object. The most-derived object is always real, and you can only assign to the most-derived object, and only assign a value of the same type. Don't go around assigning directly to base subobjects. You really need something like `typeid` to write code like that correctly. (Of course the real answer is that you should never be writing code like that.)